# I need help re-writing this method using a Java Array or ArrayList

Tags: java, mysql

I have a database table called trading_history which looks like this:

```
 +----------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
 | table_id | item_id | user_id | item_type | phone      |
 +----------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
 |        1 | 4564704 |     629 |         2 | 3656284    |
 |        2 | 4564705 |     629 |         1 | 3656284    |
 |        3 | 4564773 |     569 |         1 | 8111111    |
 |        4 | 4564792 |     351 |         2 | 0804609120 |
 |        5 | 4564825 |     569 |         1 | 8111111    |
 |        6 | 4564853 |     646 |         1 | 1111144    |
 |        7 | 4564874 |     646 |         1 | 1111144    |
 |        8 | 4564944 |     646 |         1 | 1111144    |
 |        9 | 4564964 |     105 |         2 | 3614794    |
 |       10 | 4564965 |     105 |         1 | 3614794    |
 +----------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

Fields `table_id`, and `item_id` are unique. The table records items sold by a user. Item_ids are sequential for each user, meaning that the top most item for a user is the item he sold first while the bottom most item represents the most recent item he sold.

From the above table, I want to periodically remove all items and leave only 20 most recent items sold by the user. That is, if a user has sold 100 items, I want to remove the 80 oldest items and leave him with 20. For those who have sold less than 20 in that period nothing will be removed.

I accomplished that by writing a SQL statement like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trading_history_archive LIKE trading_history;

INSERT INTO trading_history_archive
SELECT table_id, item_id , user_id,item_type,phone FROM trading_history
WHERE item_id NOT IN (
SELECT item_id 
FROM trading_history as tdg 
WHERE 20 > ( 
SELECT count(*) 
FROM trading_history AS tdg1 
WHERE tdg.user_id = tdg1.user_id 
AND tdg.item_id > tdg1.item_id ) 
ORDER BY item_id DESC );

DELETE a FROM trading_history a INNER JOIN trading_history_archive b ON    a.table_id = b.table_id;
```

However, this needs to be part of a Java application to be managed by the Scheduler. I tried creating a method using the SQL statements, but it looks clumsy and I fear SQL injection:

```
public class ArchiveTrading {
    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger (ArchiveTrading.class);
    private int sessionsArchived = 0;
.....
.....
.....
archiveTradingHistory(con,  yymm); 
.....
.....
private void archiveTradingHistory(Connection con, String yymm) {
    try {

        SqlUtil.runSqlUpdate(con, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trading_history_archive LIKE trading_history");
                    LOG.info("Finihsed creating table");
        int inserted = SqlUtil.runSqlUpdate(con, "INSERT INTO trading_history_archive " +
                        " SELECT table_id, item_id , user_id,item_type,phone FROM trading_history "+
                        " WHERE item_id NOT IN ( "+
                        " SELECT item_id  ( " +
                        " FROM trading_history as tdg  " +
                        " WHERE 20 > ( "+
                        " SELECT count(*) "+
                        " FROM trading_history AS tdg1  "+
                        " WHERE tdg.user_id = tdg1.user_id "+
                        " AND tdg.item_id > tdg1.item_id ) "+
                        " ORDER BY item_id DESC ) ");
        LOG.info("trading_history Inserted: " + inserted);
        int deleted = SqlUtil.runSqlUpdate(con, "DELETE a FROM trading_history a INNER JOIN trading_history_archive b ON a.table_id = b.table_id");
        LOG.info("trading_history Deleted: " + deleted);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (CustomDAOException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage()); 
    }
}
.....
......
}
```

Someone help me improve this so I can survive work politics.

Comment: Is archiving really what you want? Consider to use database features (indexes, etc.) and more restrictive `SELECT` statements or a "view". This reduces complexity, makes you more flexible (i.e. raising the limit to 30 becomes easy), and you don't need a scheduler.

Comment: This strikes me as bad database design and usage.  Why delete anything from the table?   Just write your views into the table to show the last twenty entries.

Comment: for periodic db queries, I strongly recommend an "operational" approach: use crontab (*nix) or AT (windows). Using java for this purpose is IMHO a waste of time and effort and is often plagued by problems.

Comment: Yes, I could achieve all that using a bash script and a simple cron job, but as I indicated, this has to fit in with the existing company application architecture. "I must" write it to use a scheduler. The database system we use is notorious for slow-response views so they're discouraged. It's a hell-ish environment

Comment: Lol @CandiedOrange. 10 years ago I'd have said exactly the same thing.  But an experienced DBA will tell you that to walk into a company with a 600 - table database, supporting 8 applications, 5000+ users; 27 million customers and an average of 1.2mi calls a day expecting the database to be well-designed is absolute fantasy. Balancing ORM support and MIS reporting is not as easy as 4NF. There's a trade-off between application persistence speed and MIS reporting efficiency. The table above is created only as an illustration.

Comment: @hlosukwakha [4NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form) wasn't my concern. I asked you WHY. Your response doesn't indicate that the database must continue to be designed badly. It indicates that you've lost control of how the DB is accessed. You're attempting to avoid "slow-response views" by creating a table with a transitory state rather then using [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_caching). The user has no idea when your last-20 update runs. Before they may see more than 20.  After they will wonder where their other trades went. Is that really your business rule?

Comment: @hlosukwakha regarding your SQL injection fears, I can't say since the only string I see coming into this is the cryptically named `yymm` which doesn't appear to be used unless it's hidden among the hand waving dots of your ellipsis ... Without seeing `yymm` used I can't tell if you've properly escaped quotes before using `yymm` in a query or are naively trusting the user not to [drop your tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).  Please use these comments to update your question.

Comment: Ok, the application was written in such a way that it displays the 5 latest items the user has worked on. To do so it has to hit the database with queries using ORDER BY, LIMIT and GROUP BY clauses which makes it very slow. So an interim solution which doesn't require an application release is to archive older items. A spec is already in place to revisit the whole logic and make it scalable